# Move a function that's used in a constructor up to that constructor's prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm taking the second Codeschool jQuery course, and the "correct" solution to one of the challenges looks conceptually as follows:

```
  function Wrapper(jQobject) {
    this.target=jQobject;

    this.fetchContentViaAJAX = function() {
    //fairly long function definition
    //...
    }

    this.target.on('click', '.child', this.fetchContentViaAJAX);
  }
```

The `Wrapper` object is basically meant to wrap a jQuery object such as `$('#some_id')` add the `fetchContentViaAJAX` method, and register a jQuery callback on the wrapped object so that when a prespecied event occurs inside that object   (here it's a 'click' on a '.child' inside the wrapped object), the `fetchContentViaAJAX()` method gets called, which modifies the wrapped object.

Now based on what I learned in their JavaScript course, this seems spatially wasteful to me. Since the `fetchContentViaAJAX` method is common to all `Wrapper` instances, it should logically belong to the `Wrapper`'s prototype, as assigning it via the constructor like this assigns an identical copy of the function to each instance of `wrapper` and thereby wastes space.

The problem is that the method is already needed in the constructor, and therefore can't be defined after the fact.

Is there an elegant solution to this (apart from making it `fetchContentViaAJAX` a global function rather than an instance method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a constructor is called, before any code is run its *this* is set to a new object and the constructor's public *prototype* is set to the new object's internal `[[prototype]]`.

So as long as the method is assigned to the prototype before calling the constructor, the method can be called from inside the constructor, e.g.:

```
// Define the constructor
function Foo(msg) {

  // call method on instance, inherited via prototype
  this.say(msg);
}

// Add method to constructor's prototype
Foo.prototype.say = function (msg) {
  alert(msg);
};

// Call constructor with new, which will call inherited method
var foo = new Foo('blah'); // blah
```

Comment: Thank you. I was testing it on virtually the same example. Didn't work for me. Turns out I forgot `new`. :D

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to function's defined on the prototype in the constructor:

```
function Thing() {
  this.init();
}

Thing.prototype.init = function() {
  console.log("I'm defined on the prototype");
};

new Thing();
```

So, you could potentially pull that function out into the prototype.

The only caveat being if that function is a closure: if the `fetchContentViaAjax` function needed to reference some variables in the local scope of the `Wrapper` function.

```
function Thing2() {
  var localState = "some local value";

  this.init = function() {
    // do something with localState
  };

  document.body.addEventListener('click', this.init);
}
```